# problemas de manejo de cámara(objetos) en pygame

Tags: python, clase, pygame

resulta que en pygame deseo que cuando el jugador su posición en x sea mayor a 300 (pantalla con ancho de 640 )entonces que el objeto "muro" se desplaze -9 en el eje x, como lo habia planteado es asi:

```
class Muro (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,archivo, x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image=pygame.image.load(archivo)
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()# Devulve ancho alto pos x pos y
        self.rect.x=x
        self.rect.y=y


    def update(self):
        if player.rect.x>300:
            self.rect.x-=9
            #el problema es que el programa solamente devuelve al usuario 
            #a la posicion 299 pero no me desplaza los objetos de la clase 
            #muro, lo retorno a la posicion 299 para que no se este 
            #desplazando el muro infinitamente
            player.rect.x=299
```

Comment: Cual es el valor del `rect.x` del muro despues del update?

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar alguna IDE para que puedas debugear tu programa, como pycharm